# Discord.py wont respond to my if statement

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, discord, discord.py

I am just beginning to learn how to code with python. I tried to make a simple truth or dare game code. But the bot is not able to provess the choice and use the if statements, i cannot figure why.
Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "Z")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is running!")

@bot.command()
async def game(ctx):
    truth_items = [(list of truth questions)]
    dare_items = [(list of dare questions)]
    await ctx.send("please type t for truth and d for dare")
    async def on_message(message):
        if(message == "t"):
            await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(truth_items)}")
        if(message == "d"):
            await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(dare_items)}")

bot.run(my_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

To receive a reply inside a command, you should use the [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) method

```
@bot.command()
async def game(ctx):
    truth_items = [(list of truth questions)]
    dare_items = [(list of dare questions)]
    await ctx.send("please type t for truth and d for dare")
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel and message.content.lower() in ("t", "d")
    message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    choice = message.content.lower()
    if choice == "t":
        await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(truth_items)}")
    if choice == "d":
        await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(dare_items)}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!